# Angular with typescript controller

Tags: angularjs, typescript, requirejs

I am using Angular + Typescript + RequireJS. After i configured all settings, simple ng-click doesn't work for me and there are NO errors in error log.

Do you guys know what I am doing wrong?
Any help will be appreciated

[image]

***My files:***

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="MasterController">
        <button ng-click="toggleModal()">777777777777</button>
    </div>
    <script src="Script/lib/require.js" type="text/javascript" data-main="Script/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Controllers.ts**

```
/// <reference path="../lib/typings/angular.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../lib/typings/jquery.d.ts" />

import angular = require("angular");

export var controllerModule = angular.module("controllers", []);
```

**MasterController.ts**

```
/// <reference path="../lib/typings/angular.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../lib/typings/require.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="controllers.ts" />

import MasterControllerModule = require("Controllers");
class MasterController {

    modalShown: boolean = true;
    constructor() {
    }

    toggleModal() {
        alert(777);
        this.modalShown = !this.modalShown;
    }

}
MasterControllerModule.controllerModule.controller("MasterController", MasterController);
```

**main.js**

```
require.config({

    paths: {

        'angular': 'lib/angular',
        'domReady': 'lib/domReady',
        'app': 'app',
        'Jquery': 'lib/jquery'
    },
    //waitSeconds: 0,
    shim: {
        'angular': {
            exports: 'angular'
        }
    },

    deps: [
        // kick start application... see bootstrap.js
        './bootstrap'
    ]
});  

 require([
  'angular',
  'app',
  'domReady',
  'controllers/Controllers',
  'controllers/MasterController',
  'Jquery'
])
```

**app.js**

```
define(['angular',
'controllers/Controllers'], function (angular) {
    return angular.module('app', ['controllers']);
});
```

**bootstrap.js**

```
define([
    'require',
    'angular',
    'app'
], function (require, ng) {
    'use strict';

    require(['domReady!'], function (document) {
        ng.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you check if scripts are getting loaded in, e.g., Chrome Dev Tools?

Comment: In angular hints i see this error :Modules were created but never loaded

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem it's in the controller class. When you use the directive `ng-click` it tries to perform the function looking inside the controllers `$scope`.

The class that you define does not inject that dependency and does nothing with the `$scope`; that's why nothing work's (In the `$scope` there is no method called `toggleModal`. You can import the `$scope` like this:

```
class MasterController {

    modalShown: boolean = true;
    static $inject = ['$scope']
    constructor($scope) {
        $scope.ctrl = this
    }

    toggleModal() {
        alert(777);
        this.modalShown = !this.modalShown;
    }
}
```

If you create the `ctrl` scope object then in your view you'll need to call it like this

```
<button ng-click="ctrl.toggleModal()">777777777777</button>
```

Take a look at [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WdtVn_8K17E) video from Bresarat Ali youtube channel for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Use Controller as syntax:

```
<div ng-controller="MasterController as vm">
```

then invoke the click method like so:

```
vm.toggleModal()
```